# How do I remove a character from array element?

Tags: ruby, arrays, replace

I have an array like this:

```
["ee", "3/4\"", "22\"", "22\""]
```

and I'd like to either remove the commas, `\"` or replace that with `&#34` so that the array looks like this:

```
["ee", "3/4", "22", "22"]
```

or this:

```
["ee", "3/4&#34", "22&#34", "22&#34"]
```

The reason is that I'm trying to pass that array from Ruby to JavaScript, but I keep getting an "Unterminated string constant error" and I just can't figure out a way around it!

This is what I'm using to pass the info to JavaScript:

```
cut_list="from_ruby_cut(\""+c[1]+"\")"
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using JSON?

Comment: Yes.. I have no idea what JSON is... :) I'm pretty new at all this programming stuff and so my knowledge is pretty limited, unfortunetly. I'll look into JSON and see if that could help.

Comment: Shouldn't the `&#` entity end with a semicolon? (e.g., `&#34;`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To replace each element in an array with a modified version, such as replacing the unwanted character, you can use the `map!` function. Inside the block, use `gsub` to replace the unwanted `"` character.

```
array = ["ee", "3/4\"", "22\"", "22\""]

array.map!{ |element| element.gsub(/"/, '') }
array
#=> ["ee", "3/4", "22", "22"]

array.map!{ |element| element.gsub(/"/, '&#34') }
array
#=> ["ee", "3/4&#34", "22&#34", "22&#34"]
```

However, you may also be able to solve your problem by using `c[1].inspect` instead of `c[1]` when building your JavaScript string. If you use inspect, it'll print the string with the enclosing quotes included, and the backslash to escape the quote inside the string.

Comment: Using .inspect worked, Pure genious!! And sadly for me pretty simple solution... I will play around with the rest of your suggestion as it might come in handy at another time. Thanks Emily!

Answer (score 0):

To modify the arrays the way you want use `map` and gsub.

```
a = ["ee", "3/4\"", "22\"", "22\""]
a.map{|e| e.gsub(/"/,'')}
=> ["ee", "3/4", "22", "22"]
```

or

```
a.map{|e| e.gsub(/"/,'&#34')}
=> ["ee", "3/4&#34", "22&#34", "22&#34"]
```

However, I am not sure this is the best way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best way either but hey it's fun learning something new. :) Thanks for your reply NullRef.