# How can remove some special character from string of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def valid_sheet_names
   Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).reject(&:nil?).map(&:downcase)
end

["hardware", "computer", "network", "mobile devices"]
```

this function return an array.i want to remove space, dot and underscore from string. but i don'y know how can i do this

Comment: Do you expect to get an array of strings without characters you want to be removed?

Comment: yes i want to removed that characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a character from array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641077/how-do-i-remove-a-character-from-array-element)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The same way you `map` over the collection, you can iterate it using a block:

```rb
["hardware", "computer", "network", "mobile devices"].map do |asset_type|
  asset_type.delete(' ')
            .delete('_')
            .delete('.')
end
```

Your function could look something like:

```rb
def valid_sheet_names
  asset_types = Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).reject(&:nil?)

  # I'd personally extract normalization to a specific function or module
  asset_types.map do |asset_type|
    asset_type.downcase
              .delete(' ')
              .delete('.')
              .delete('_')
  end
end
```

You can also use `gsub` (which supports regular expressions). Though I found `delete` more explicit when we want to... delete

Answer (score 1):

I would filter `nil` values within the database query and avoid loading them into memory first. Then I would sanitize the names with one `tr` call:

```
def valid_sheet_names
  Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.where.not(name: nil).pluck(:name)
  names.map { |name| name.downcase.tr(' ._', '') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Sumak's @spickermann's answers

```rb
["hardware", "computer", "network", "mobile devices"].map do |asset_type|
  asset_type.gsub(/[._\s]/, '')
end
```

Which would piece into your code like this

```rb
def valid_sheet_names
 Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).reject(&:nil?).map { |name| name.downcase.gsub(/[._\s]/, '') }
end
```

`gsub` is preferred here to take advantage of the metacharacter `\s` which grabs any type of whitespace.